# How to update multiple product in Shopify API using Laravel

Tags: laravel, shopify

I'm able to insert almost 20 products if they don't have any variants. Still, if I add variants, only the first item is inserted, and its variant details are updated. I have almost 20 products, but only the first product is getting updated. I'm getting an error after the first product gets updated.

**Client error**

> PUT
> https://livingdemotwo.myshopify.com/admin/products/6896286957725.json
> resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:
> {"errors":{"name":["of Option is not unique"]}}

```
// $getcount is 20 for now
for ($i = 0; $i < $getcount; $i++) {
    $test['product']['title'] = $data[$i]['ItemDescription'];
    $test['product']['published'] = "false";
    $test['product']['product_type'] = $data[$i]['ItemCategory'];

    $test['product']['vendor'] = $data[$i]['BrandName'];
    $test['product']['status'] = "draft";
    // inserting data
    $shopifyCustomers = $newtest->api()->rest('POST', '/admin/products.json', $test);
    // variants
    $test3['product']['variants'][] = [
        "option1" => $data[$i]['FrontColour'],
        "option2" => $data[$i]['Size'],
        "price" => $data[$i]['Price'],
        "inventory_quantity" => $this->getstock($data[$i]['ItemCode']),
        "sku" => $data[$i]['ItemCode'],
    ];
    $test3['product']['options'][] = [
        "name" => "Color",
        "values" => [
            $data[$i]['FrontColour'],
        ],
    ];
    $test3['product']['options'][] = [
        "name" => "Size",
        "values" => [
            $data[$i]['Size'],
        ]
    ];
    // updating data
    $shopifyCustomers2 = $newtest->api()->rest('PUT',
        '/admin/products/'.
        $shopifyCustomers['body']['container']['product']['id'].'.json', $test3);
```

Comment: what do you think that we can understand in this code? show about refactoring the code and isolate the problem to a smaller and cleaner piece of code?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia ok i have removed some lines from my code

Comment: Without knowing the contents of `$data` it is not possible to understand this. Because probably you are sending same data for different variants and Shopify API complains about their uniqueness.

Comment: @UğurArıcı no data is loop with 20 different items

Comment: Please see [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If the problem is in the data, probably we need to see the data to help.  But we probably don't need to see 20 data items - 2 should be enough to generate a non-unique error, right?  Try to create the simplest possible case which displays the problem.